# Price level calculation

Tags: inflation

I am currently reading [Dying of Money](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1457502666) by Jens O. Parsson and he criticizes the way price level is calculated. Basically he tries to make a case that since money are not only used to purchase goods but also used for investing, there are two money supplies and two velocities at the same time:

> There are at all times two distinct money supplies and two distinct
> velocities of money, one each in the market for national product and
> the market for national wealth ["investments"]. The comparison between
> the total supply of money and the gross national product alone, as is
> made in computing the so-called "income velocity" of money, is
> meaningless.

First, I wonder what does he mean by two distinct money supplies? Where does the second supply come from? Is it like **borrowed money**?

Second, is there a velocity metric for investments or maybe even inflation metric too?

Comment: I am unaware of anyone else using the concept. Ideally, you could find a reference in the public domain where the idea is described in more depth. The only people who could give an answer to this question would need to read the book and get a longer explanation - if it exists.

Comment: As brian says this sort of distinction is not made by conventional economists. In addition, I tried to google the author and found interview where even the author says he never had any economics education. Consequently, it is unlikely that economists will be able to tell you what he meant. In addition, I doubt that any statistical office would craft statistics based on that.

Comment: I read a lot of market analysis which can get pretty loopy, and I still have never heard of this concept. If there are two money supply measures, the person who is defining them has to state what the components are.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk, 1muflon1 fair enough, well the book is indeed written in 70s and the author is a lawyer. That being said he makes an interesting case, that inflation moves initially to markets and from markets into prices of goods. It would be interesting to find some data to back this up e.g. amount of money in stocks/bonds and velocity of it.

Comment: You could try finding explanations of the Cantillon Effect. This is a popular idea among Austrian economists. (Austrians are named such because the “founders” were mainly from Austria. It is a libertarian school of thought that rejects mainstream economics.)

Comment: @spacemonkey Just to get back to your point about “money invested in stocks and bonds”: the money used to pay for a stock or bond just goes to the seller. The seller can do whatever they want wit it. There’s no way to draw a line between different types of “money” for these purposes. That’s why we can’t really answer the question.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk I wonder how far off `market cap / volume` would be as a measure of velocity?

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk although, volume as money supply would be tricky though. Maybe aggregating with max function over certain periods. I admit, I am reaching here. It is strange though that "investments" are completely ignored when we talk about inflation, like what do economists expect, that the money just going to stay there?

Comment: There are probably questions about asset prices being in the CPI, notably housing. Economists leave them out for very good reasons. That’s another issue.